# How to Process XML Data using Jolt transformation in Apache Nifi

Tags: json, xml, xslt, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>abcd</Name>
</Header>
<Category>
<CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
<Name>abc</Name>
<SubCategory>
<SubID>10</SubID>
<Type>A</Type>
</SubCategory>
<SubCategory>
<SubID>11</SubID>
<Type>B</Type>
</SubCategory>
</Category>
<Category>
<CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
<Name>def</Name>
<SubCategory>
<SubID>10</SubID>
<Type>A</Type>
</SubCategory>
<SubCategory>
<SubID>11</SubID>
<Type>B</Type>
</SubCategory>
</Category>
```

How to transform this XML into JSON using JoltTransformRecord in apache nifi. I want to extract Each Subcategory Data with CategoryID from xml.

Any help in this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Jolt produces output of type JSON from a JSON input.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the reply.. I have seen examples of transforming xml to json using jolt?? but if not jolt then how to transform xml to json in apache nifi??

Comment: It is possible. Use JoltTransformRecord with xmlreader and jsonwriter. But if you don't need to transform you could use ConvertRecord - it should be easier to configure.

Comment: Hi @daggett Thanks for the reply I have used convert record to convert into json then I have records in one to many relation then I used jolt it make the array of records like  id = 1,Type = [a,b,c] etc in json. now I am confused how to get array records with id and convert it into sql would you please help me to convert json like this in to sql?

Comment: @daggett you can see above xml if you are confused about my comment i want to insert e.g. categoryid,subcategoryid,Subcategory type in mysql table thats why 1st I have to make json like that and then convert json into sql could you please help me